# php mysql insert the data, but it was in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i have this data and im calling it using mysql select then while row fetch array

here is my image of the database
[image]

on top of that database there is save button
so when i do save the data, it only save the first row but not the second row.

here is my `insert code` its kinda long data

```
// COUNTER
$cou = $_POST['cou'];

// USER DETAILS
$user_code = $_POST['user_code'];
$com_code = $_POST['ccode'];    
$com_for_track = $_POST['atrack'];
$template_code = $_POST['template_code'];

$logo_position = $_POST['logo_position'];
$logo_width = $_POST['logo_width'];

$add_position = $_POST['add_position'];
$font_size = $_POST['font_size'];
$font_family = $_POST['font_family'];

// FOR COMPANY NAME
$com_name = $_POST['com_name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$post_code = $_POST['post_code'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$kvk_no = $_POST['kvk_no'];
$vat_no = $_POST['vat_no'];
$bank_acct = $_POST['bank_acct'];
$bank_acct_iban = $_POST['bank_acct_iban'];

// CLIENT NAME
$com_name_for = $_POST['com_name_for'];
$sub_quo = $_POST['sub_quo'];
$street_name_for = $_POST['street_name_for'];
$post_code_for = $_POST['post_code_for'];
$city_for = $_POST['city_for'];
$country_for = $_POST['country_for'];

$todays = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['todays'] ) );
$ex_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['ex_date'] ) );

$fact_year = $_POST['fact_year'];
$inv_num = $_POST['inv_num'];

// COMPUTATION
$quan = $_POST['quan'];
$defi = $_POST['defi'];
$amti = $_POST['amti'];
$tota = $_POST['tota'];
$btwi = $_POST['btwi'];

// SUBTOTAL
$total_f = $_POST['total_f'];
$s_btw = $_POST['s_btw'];
$t_com = $_POST['t_com'];

// FOOTER 
$ft = $_POST['ft'];

$i = 1;
while ( $i <= $cou ) {
JON_SQL( "INSERT INTO jon_tem VALUE( ''
,'$user_code'
,'$com_code'
,'$com_for_track'
,'$template_code'
,'$logo_position'
,'$logo_width'
,'$add_position'
,'$font_size'
,'$font_family'
,'$com_name'
,'$address'
,'$post_code'
,'$city'
,'$country'
,'$email'
,'$kvk_no'
,'$vat_no'
,'$bank_acct'
,'$bank_acct_iban'
,'$com_name_for'
,'$sub_quo'
,'$street_name_for'
,'$post_code_for'
,'$city_for'
,'$country_for'
,'$todays'
,'$ex_date'
,'$fact_year'
,'$inv_num'
,'$quan'
,'$defi'
,'$amti'
,'$tota'
,'$btwi'
,'$total_f'
,'$s_btw'
,'$t_com'
,NOW() )" );

$i++;
}

echo '<div id="success">New template has been saved! <a href="index.php?c=cprof">Quotation Settings</a></div>';
```

if you see i put `while there` but its not workin, well yes its working and it loop it 3 times or bla bla but again it only save the first row data.

how can i fix it? :(

Comment: `$_POST['bank_acct'];` with this script!?!?! Wow.

Comment: From the look of your code at a quick glance it seems like you would only be entering one set of data, even though you might loop three times it wouldn't matter if the data is the same. Basically your just doing the same thing three times.

Comment: You are trying to save 3 times the same values; probably there is unique constrain that fails after the first time the rows is inserted

Comment: @stevenfarley do i need to use `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly fixed it.

heres is the updated code.

```
$i = 1;
while ( $i <= $cou ) {

// COMPUTATION
$quan = $_POST['quan_'.$i];
$defi = $_POST['defi_'.$i];
$amti = $_POST['amti_'.$i];
$tota = $_POST['tota_'.$i];
$btwi = $_POST['btwi_'.$i];

JON_SQL( "INSERT INTO jon_tem VALUE( ''
,'$user_code'
,'$com_code'
,'$com_for_track'
,'$template_code'
,'$logo_position'
,'$logo_width'
,'$add_position'
,'$font_size'
,'$font_family'
,'$com_name'
,'$address'
,'$post_code'
,'$city'
,'$country'
,'$email'
,'$kvk_no'
,'$vat_no'
,'$bank_acct'
,'$bank_acct_iban'
,'$com_name_for'
,'$sub_quo'
,'$street_name_for'
,'$post_code_for'
,'$city_for'
,'$country_for'
,'$todays'
,'$ex_date'
,'$fact_year'
,'$inv_num'
,'$quan'
,'$defi'
,'$amti'
,'$tota'
,'$btwi'
,'$total_f'
,'$s_btw'
,'$t_com'
,NOW() )" );

$i++;
}
```

and the html code

```
$i = 1;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlview ) ) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['category'];?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="atrack" value="<?=$row['com_track'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quan_<?=$i;?>" value="<?=$row['quo_quantity'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="defi_<?=$i;?>" value="<?=$row['quo_definition'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amti_<?=$i;?>" value="<?=$row['quo_amt'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tota_<?=$i;?>" value="<?=$row['quo_total'];?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="btwi_<?=$i;?>" value="<?=$row['quo_btw'];?>" />
            <?=$row['quo_quantity'];?> x
        </td>
        <td width="200">
            <?=$row['quo_definition'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$msg_tot;?> <?=$row['quo_amt'];?>
        </td>
        <td id="total">
            <input type="hidden" name="sumof" value="<?=$row['quo_total'];?>" />
            <?=$msg_tot;?> <?=$row['quo_total'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$row['quo_btw'];?>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <?
 $i++;
}
```

thank you guys for the idea. very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You area sending single elements, you have to send array of data for you to save array of data.